# Visual Studio c# Array Loop

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010

I'm not sure if this has been asked before but I couldn't see it anywhere.

Can you loop an array? For example:

```
string[] = array1;
int num1 = 1;

do
{
    lbl1.Text = array1[0]
}while(num1 = 1);
```

How can I make it so it adds one to the element every loop.

Comment: You are going to have to be a lot clearer about what you are trying to accomplish. Can you loop through an array? Yes. Can you modify it when you loop through it? Yes. Can you do what you have above? I have no idea because its not clear what you are trying to do. Looks like you want to use a `for` loop instead of a do...while loop, but it would be trivial to put `num1+=1` inside the loop, then use `array1[num1]`, but a lot of your code is just not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that you need to better explain what you're trying to accomplish. If you hardcode num1 then perform a while num1 is equal to its initial value without ever modifying it, you're going to have an indefinite loop. In your example, it will just keep overwriting lbl1 to display the first item in your array.

By "add one to the element every loop", do you mean add each item in the array to your label? Try something like...

```
foreach (string item in array1)
{
     lbl1.Text += array1[item];
}
```

Otherwise, please provide further details on what you're looking for.

Comment: I just wanted to display the arrays contents into a label one by one with an event driven trigger like a button or something similar without having to write the code over and over for each array element, anyway you described what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Just be sure to try to use more concise wording when asking a question in the future to avoid the downvotes and keep us from scratching our heads. :)

Comment: Sure, apologies for my bad wording :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is really not clear what You want to achieve, but maybe this will get You nearer to the goal:

```
int[] array1 = new [] {0};
int num1 = 1;
do {
       lbl1.Text = (array1[0]++).ToString();
       num1++;
} while (num1 < 9);
```

or

```
int[] array1 = new [] {0};
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        lbl1.Text = (array1[0]++).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish but the following is a stab at a solution

```
private static void foo(string[] array1)
{
  if (array1 != null && array1.Length > 0)
  {
    for (int num1 = 0; num1 < array1.Length; num1++)
    {
        string doSomethingWithArrayElement = array1[num1];
    }
  }
}
```